# Комплексные числа в c++

Tags: c++, qt, qtcreator

У меня есть функция типа complex, которая возвращает комплексное число. Я хочу вывести результат в виджет Qlabel, однако метод setNum этого не позволяет. Как вывести комплексное число в Qlabel?

Comment: Напишите функцию для преобразования комплексного числа в QString, и используйте setText.

Answer (score 1):

напишем вот такую страшную функцию

```
template<typename T>
std::string to_string(std::complex<T> n)
{
    return std::to_string(n.real()) + ((n.imag()>=0)?"+":"") + std::to_string(n.imag()) + "i";
}
```

(ее можно упростить, но это пусть будет домашнее задание)

И теперь можно писать вот так

```
std::complex<double> z1 = 1-1i;
std::string zs = to_string(z1);
```

А потом использовать label1.setText(...)

Правда лучше будет переделать исходную функцию на QString

```
template<typename T>
QString to_string(std::complex<T> n)
{
    return QString(n.real()) + ((n.imag()>=0)?"+":"") + QString(n.imag()) + "i";
}
```

Если же хочется вывода как в стандартной библиотеке (в виде `(1,-3)` ), то это даже проще

```
template<typename T>
QString to_string(std::complex<T> n)
{
    return QString("(%1,%2)").arg(n.real()).arg(n.imag());
}
```

P.S. А почему шаблоны? да просто сам тип комплексного числа также шаблонный и что бы не писать на каждый возможный тип свою функцию, воспользуемся шаблонами.